# How to center a bootstrap container inside a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) to show a image gallery. Now I want to center the entire bootstrap `.container` within a `div (.abc)`. Here is the link to the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tn3j2kos/

Code below -

```css
.abc {
  margin: auto;
  width: 96%;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}
.imgframe {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
}
div img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 70px;
  max-width: 110px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="abc">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="imgframe col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail">
          <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="imgframe col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail">
          <img src="https://mozorg.cdn.mozilla.net/media/img/styleguide/identity/firefox/usage-logo.png?2013-06" />
        </div>
        <div class="imgframe col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail">
          <img src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="imgframe col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail">
          <img src="https://g.twimg.com/About_logoUsage.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="imgframe col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 thumbnail">
          <img src="https://g.twimg.com/About_logoUsage.png" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**More details -** The sample in fiddle has five thumbnails. I want the thumbnails within the `div .row` to be left aligned. And the group of thumbnails (inside `div .container`) to be center aligned inside `div .abc`.

My several attempts have failed, and I posted the code for my last attempt.

**EDIT -** Don't bother running code snippet inside SO as it is rendering incorrectly. Use js fiddle I posted at top instead.

**EDIT 2 -** Perhaps I can explain what I want to achieve through this equation `container_width = no_of_thumb*(thumb_width+margin*2)`.

**EDIT 3 -** How it appears-

[image]

How I want it to appear-

[image]

Comment: not sure i understand what you are trying to achieve... `.container` is automatically centered by bootstrap (inspect it, or give it an outline and you'll see). Also you should not tamper with the dimensions and padding/margin of your `.col-` classes (`.imgframe`), or you'll break the grid system! Perhaps an image of what you are trying to achieve could be useful...

Comment: @PeterVR: Please check my EDIT 2, if it makes my goal clearer.

Comment: euhm, no, not really... You always want all your thumbs on a single row? A simple mockup would still be more useful I think...

Comment: @PeterVR: I have added screenshots now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the workings of bootstrap a bit:

- `.container` should be your outer most wrapper, or you could use `.container-fluid` in stead
- `.col-` classes determine width and padding/margin of the block they are aplied to. Messing with these values will break the responsiveness. Use a wrapper inside those `.col` blocks in stead if you need to play with dimensions.
- why are you positioning those images absolute? I don't see what you are trying to achieve...

I went ahead and cleaned up your fiddle a bit. I think this may be what you are after: http://jsfiddle.net/tn3j2kos/4/embedded/result/

HTML:

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                <img class='img-responsive' src=#" />
            </div>
            ....
```

CSS:

```
.abc {
    background-color: #ffffcc;
    padding: 0 4%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just set `.container` to `display: inline-block` and call `text-align: center` on `.abc`

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tn3j2kos/1/)

Comment: Thanks, this works if I set the width for `.container` appropriately. But if I resize the screen so that (lets say) only 2 thumbnails are visible on a row. Then I want to adjust the width of container, so that the group aligns in center. 

In other words I want to adjust `container_width = no_of_thumb*(thumb_width+margin*2)`